How to sign a non-VSTO Excel COM add-in written in C#? Should I implement a shim loader or migrate to VSTO?
I developed an Excel add-in using the NetOffice libraries in C#. The add-in is currently loaded by Excel using the default loader (mscoree.dll) and because of this Excel always recognizes it as not signed.
For years I had no problems, but now I need to properly sign the add-in so that Excel recognizes it as trusted.
If I have not misunderstood by documenting myself on the internet, the alternatives are as follows:

Develop an ad-hoc loader (COM shim).
Migrate the whole project to VSTO.

However, it is not clear to me which of the two is actually the better solution. It seems that the “official” Microsoft solution is to use VSTO, however, all the Excel add-ins I have found around still seem not to use it, and I wonder why...
On the other hand though, all the documentation I find regarding COM shims seems to be outdated, for example I see that the COM shim whizard is only supported up to VisualStudio 2010.
So do you recommend that I migrate to VSTO once and for all, or implement a custom shim loader?

A bit rusty about all that but they are basically the same, with VSTO being a wrapper around COM interfaces and providing lots of tooling above raw COM. VSTO is still fully supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/visual-studio-tools-for-office-runtime

Either way should be easy enough.

Thank you, but I am not questioning the ease. I am wondering which of the two paths is best to follow. If VSTO seems the more official and supported way, how come all the addins I find around, including those that come with Excel itself, seem not to use that technology? If, on the other hand, the shim loader solution is the most widely used, how come the documentation I find on the net is outdated (2010 and older)? Is there another more suitable way nowadays to build an Excel addin that I have not considered?
